# Can not insert bibliogarphy to LaTeX

Tags: latex, bibtex

I am very new using LaTeX by TeX Maker.

When i try to give bibliography with

```
\cite{sevgican2020intelligent}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{references.bib}
```

while my .bib doc includes the key and other information with

```
@article{sevgican2020intelligent,
  title={Intelligent network data analytics function in 5G cellular networks using machine learning},
  author={Sevgican, Salih and Turan, Meri{\c{c}} and G{\"o}karslan, Kerim and Yilmaz, H Birkan and Tugcu, Tuna},
  journal={Journal of Communications and Networks},
  volume={22},
  number={3},
  pages={269--280},
  year={2020},
  publisher={KICS}
}
```

Whenever I try to insert bibliography it gives **Citation `sevgican2020intelligent' on page 1 undefined** error.

When searched for the solution online, there are so many other people who had faced with this issue once. But unfortunately none of the answers could solve my problem.

Some resources, like *overleaf*, recommend to use

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic, ieeetr,
sorting=ynt
]{biblatex}
```

While i am using:

```
\usepackage{cite}
```

Even when I try their recommendation, it throws more errors and warnings.

Can anyone help me to solve my problem please? Thank you for your time any way.

Comment: With traditional bibtex, you should use `\bibliography{references}` instead of `\bibliography{references.bib}`. Otherwise your code fragments work fine if I add enough code to actually compile them. Please add a [mre] to your question. Also check if you compile with bibtex.

Comment: When i deleted .bib like you said, and turn that into `\bibliography{references}` it also throws another warning which *Empty `thebibliography' environment*. Also, i am adding a minimal reprex to my question Sir.

Comment: Please add a [mre] to your question. It should be a short compilable document, starting with a documenclass, the necessary packages and a short document body which allows us to reproduce the problem. Your empty bibliography can have many reasons. We need to start from a common ground so we can see what problem might be or might not be in your document.

Answer (score -1):

I also just biblatex for my bibliography and I have never had any trouble with it. The only thing to keep in mind is that you need to use \printbibliography to display it.

Start tying with the most standard way and see if you get any errors. If it works fine you can start adding arguments to get it exactly how you want:

\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\printbibliography